# How can change div textContent without use getElementsByName or getElementsById?

Tags: javascript

How can change div `textContent` without use `getElementsByName` or `getElementsById`?

I have a code like this :

```
function get_up_vote_text() {
    var up_text=document.createElement('div');
    up_text.setAttribute('name','up_text');
    up_text.textContent='152';

    return up_text;
}
```

And I want update "up_text" value in the following function (without using `getElementsByName` or `getElementsById`) :

```
function get_up_vote() {
    var up = document.createElement('div');
    up.setAttribute('name','up');

    up.onclick=function () {
        var temp=get_up_vote_text();
        //I want write some code here to update "up_text" value 
    }
    return up;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid using `getElementById()`, etc? What problem are you trying to solve? Arbitrary exclusion of relevant and valid code really needs to be explained.

Comment: @DavidThomas True... I understand nothing in this question.

Comment: in fact i want generate forms with jquery.  
suppose you create a form.js which contains some function to generate a forms(form contain image, text box and button). forms have been generate dynamically by user.  
if user click on button, text box contain update. how can i use getElementById()?
@DavidThomas


(I apologize for poor writing)

Comment: First, you need to properly explain the problem you're trying to solve. I'd suggest asking a new question, after all this time, because the question you meant to ask is not the question you asked. (Whether you delete this question or not is up to you, though, since all answers are without up-votes.) But before you post a new question, search the site to be sure it hasn't been asked before. Then - if you still need to ask - explain your problem clearly. Including the code (JavaScript, HTML and CSS) that you've tried, and descriptions of what failed, and how.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this` object :

```
up.onclick=function () {
    var temp=get_up_vote_text();

    this.textContent="new text content";
}
```

OR also from event using `e.target` :

```
up.onclick=function (e) {
    var temp=get_up_vote_text();

    e.target.textContent="new text content";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for it, use these tags on your HTML page

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

then if your div has a id = divID simply use $("#divID") to get the div you want